# How to check if parent element contains a certain tag? - Polymer

Tags: javascript, html, polymer

I have code split into different files as such (simplified version):

**admin-page.html**

```
<paper-tabs selected={{selected}} attr-for-selecton="name">
    <paper-tab name="User">User</paper-tab>
    ...
    ...
</paper-tabs>
<iron-pages selected={{selected}} attr-for-selection="name">
    <admin-user-page name="User"></admin-user-page>
    ...
    ...
</iron-pages>
```

**admin-user-page.html**

```
<!-- general page content... -->

// Javascript
//--------------
// here I want to have an if statement for whether the parent (user-page.html) 
// contains the <paper-tabs> tag.
```

Bearing in mind that I'm after a PolymerJS solution to this, is there any way of detecting whether `paper-tabs` is present in **admin-page.html** from within the **admin-user-page.html** file?

Comment: Why do you want to do that? Couldn't you pass a flag or something to your admin-user-page component? I think is a little bit elegant

Comment: I have literally no idea what you mean XD

Answer (score 2):

Well, within your child component (admin-user-page) you could use **this.parentNode** to access your parent component (admin-page) and then check whether there is a paper-tabs tag. So it would look something like this:

```
Polymer('admin-user-page', {
  ready: function(){
     // you have to use parentNode twice
     // this.parentNode is the iron-pages
     // this.parentNode.parentNode is the admin-page
     if( this.parentNode.parentNode.querySelector('paper-tabs') ){
       // paper-tabs tag exists in parent
     }
  }
});
```

It is not an elegant solution though. But I hope that answers your question.

Comment: I will give it a go and report back Simon! Thanks for the input :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try [`closest(selectors)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest):

```
this.closest('paper-tabs')
```